# Multiprocessing: writing into a hdf5 file

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, hdf5, h5py

I am running a parallelized code in Python and I am trying to save some values within each iteration. My code could be simplified/summarized as follows:

```
# Import necessary libraries

def func(a,b):
    # Generate some data and save it into "vector".
    
    # Create a Hdf5 file and save data in vector.
    with h5py.File('/some_file.hdf5', 'w') as f:

        f.create_dataset('data_set', data=vector)

# Some code

# Parallelize func
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool(2) as p:
        [p.apply_async(func, args=(elem, b)) for elem in big_array]
```

I am saving the files while parallelizing to save memory, since I will be working with big amounts of data.

However, every time I run the script, no hdf5 file is generated and the data is not saved.

I am pretty new to Parallelization with Python and I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: To write an HDF5 file in parallel with h5py, both HDF5 and h5py must be compiled with Parallel HDF5 enabled (MPI support turned on). This is accomplished through the mpi4py Python package. Complete details are in [the h5py docs](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html).

Comment: Thanks kcw78!

I had a quick look at `mpi5py` and it does not seem to be very easy to implement. Could you give me an example of how to do it?

I am currently using `multiprocessing`, would it be possible to do it with it so that I do not have to modify the core of the parallelization in my code?

Comment: Sorry, I have only read the docs, and have not used `mpi4py`. There is a h5py specific forum on [The HDF Group Forum](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/c/hdf-tools/h5py). That might be your best source for details to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I changed the `with` command (last two lines) by the following:

```
p = mp.Pool(2)
result = [p.apply_async(func, args=(elem, b)) for elem in big_array]
p.close()
p.join()
```

and it worked!

It seems the previous code, with the `with` command, basically leaves the `for` loop when the tasks are assigned to each processor and leaves the loop before all calculations are done.